# NamedPipeServerStream in Mono

Tags: c#, monodevelop, .net, namedpipeserverstream

I am trying to convert C#.Net project into Mono. NamedPipeServerStream & NamedPipeClientStream class are not supporting in Mono and throwing Unhandle exception.
Could you please help me anyone?

**Code:**

```
class Program
{
    static string _PipeName = "testPipe";
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        ListenForPipeServer();
    }

    static void ListenForPipeServer()
    {
        using (NamedPipeServerStream pipeServer = new NamedPipeServerStream(
                          _PipeName,
                          PipeDirection.InOut,
                          2,
                          PipeTransmissionMode.Message,
                          PipeOptions.None

                          ))
        {
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(pipeServer);
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(pipeServer);


            do
            {
                try
                {
                    pipeServer.WaitForConnection();
                    sw.WriteLine("Testing");
                    sw.Flush();
                    pipeServer.WaitForPipeDrain();
                    Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadLine());

                }
                catch (Exception)
                {

                    throw;
                }
                finally
                {

                    pipeServer.WaitForPipeDrain();
                    if (pipeServer.IsConnected) pipeServer.Disconnect();
                }

            } while (true);

        }
    }



}
```

**Unhandled Exception:**

> System.IO.IOException: Error on creating named pipe: error code -1
>   at System.IO.Pipes.UnixNamedPipe.EnsureTargetFile (System.String name)
>   [0x0001f] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/mono-mac-ui-refresh-2-10/2baeee2f/source/bockbuild/profiles/mono-2-10/build-root/mono-2.10.11/_build/mono-2.10.11.git/mcs/class/System.Core/System.IO.Pipes/PipeUnix.cs:131
>   at System.IO.Pipes.UnixNamedPipeServer..ctor
>   (System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeServerStream owner, System.String pipeName,
>   Int32 maxNumberOfServerInstances, PipeTransmissionMode
>   transmissionMode, PipeAccessRights rights, PipeOptions options, Int32
>   inBufferSize, Int32 outBufferSize, HandleInheritability
>   inheritability) [0x00012] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/mono-mac-ui-refresh-2-10/2baeee2f/source/bockbuild/profiles/mono-2-10/build-root/mono-2.10.11/_build/mono-2.10.11.git/mcs/class/System.Core/System.IO.Pipes/PipeUnix.cs:265
>   at System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeServerStream..ctor (System.String
>   pipeName, PipeDirection direction, Int32 maxNumberOfServerInstances,
>   PipeTransmissionMode transmissionMode, PipeOptions options, Int32
>   inBufferSize, Int32 outBufferSize, System.IO.Pipes.PipeSecurity
>   pipeSecurity, HandleInheritability inheritability, PipeAccessRights
>   additionalAccessRights) [0x0004b] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/mono-mac-ui-refresh-2-10/2baeee2f/source/bockbuild/profiles/mono-2-10/build-root/mono-2.10.11/_build/mono-2.10.11.git/mcs/class/System.Core/System.IO.Pipes/NamedPipeServerStream.cs:100
>   at System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeServerStream..ctor (System.String
>   pipeName, PipeDirection direction, Int32 maxNumberOfServerInstances,
>   PipeTransmissionMode transmissionMode, PipeOptions options, Int32
>   inBufferSize, Int32 outBufferSize, System.IO.Pipes.PipeSecurity
>   pipeSecurity, HandleInheritability inheritability) [0x00000] in
>   :0    at System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeServerStream..ctor
>   (System.String pipeName, PipeDirection direction, Int32
>   maxNumberOfServerInstances, PipeTransmissionMode transmissionMode,
>   PipeOptions options, Int32 inBufferSize, Int32 outBufferSize,
>   System.IO.Pipes.PipeSecurity pipeSecurity) [0x00000] in :0    at System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeServerStream..ctor
>   (System.String pipeName, PipeDirection direction, Int32
>   maxNumberOfServerInstances, PipeTransmissionMode transmissionMode,
>   PipeOptions options, Int32 inBufferSize, Int32 outBufferSize)
>   [0x00000] in :0    at
>   System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeServerStream..ctor (System.String pipeName,
>   PipeDirection direction, Int32 maxNumberOfServerInstances,
>   PipeTransmissionMode transmissionMode, PipeOptions options) [0x00000]
>   in :0    at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check)
>   System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeServerStream:.ctor
>   (string,System.IO.Pipes.PipeDirection,int,System.IO.Pipes.PipeTransmissionMode,System.IO.Pipes.PipeOptions)
>   at ConsoleTestPipeApp1.Program.ListenForPipeServer () [0x00000] in
>   /Users/Vadivelu/Project/Service_Test/ConsoleTestPipeApp1/ConsoleTestPipeApp1/Program.cs:21
>   at ConsoleTestPipeApp1.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000]
>   in
>   /Users/Vadivelu/Project/Service_Test/ConsoleTestPipeApp1/ConsoleTestPipeApp1/Program.cs:16
>   [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.IO.IOException: Error on
>   creating named pipe: error code -1   at
>   System.IO.Pipes.UnixNamedPipe.EnsureTargetFile (System.String name)
>   [0x0001f] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/mono-mac-ui-refresh-2-10/2baeee2f/source/bockbuild/profiles/mono-2-10/build-root/mono-2.10.11/_build/mono-2.10.11.git/mcs/class/System.Core/System.IO.Pipes/PipeUnix.cs:131
>   at System.IO.Pipes.UnixNamedPipeServer..ctor
>   (System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeServerStream owner, System.String pipeName,
>   Int32 maxNumberOfServerInstances, PipeTransmissionMode
>   transmissionMode, PipeAccessRights rights, PipeOptions options, Int32
>   inBufferSize, Int32 outBufferSize, HandleInheritability
>   inheritability) [0x00012] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/mono-mac-ui-refresh-2-10/2baeee2f/source/bockbuild/profiles/mono-2-10/build-root/mono-2.10.11/_build/mono-2.10.11.git/mcs/class/System.Core/System.IO.Pipes/PipeUnix.cs:265
>   at System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeServerStream..ctor (System.String
>   pipeName, PipeDirection direction, Int32 maxNumberOfServerInstances,
>   PipeTransmissionMode transmissionMode, PipeOptions options, Int32
>   inBufferSize, Int32 outBufferSize, System.IO.Pipes.PipeSecurity
>   pipeSecurity, HandleInheritability inheritability, PipeAccessRights
>   additionalAccessRights) [0x0004b] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/mono-mac-ui-refresh-2-10/2baeee2f/source/bockbuild/profiles/mono-2-10/build-root/mono-2.10.11/_build/mono-2.10.11.git/mcs/class/System.Core/System.IO.Pipes/NamedPipeServerStream.cs:100
>   at System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeServerStream..ctor (System.String
>   pipeName, PipeDirection direction, Int32 maxNumberOfServerInstances,
>   PipeTransmissionMode transmissionMode, PipeOptions options, Int32
>   inBufferSize, Int32 outBufferSize, System.IO.Pipes.PipeSecurity
>   pipeSecurity, HandleInheritability inheritability) [0x00000] in
>   :0    at System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeServerStream..ctor
>   (System.String pipeName, PipeDirection direction, Int32
>   maxNumberOfServerInstances, PipeTransmissionMode transmissionMode,
>   PipeOptions options, Int32 inBufferSize, Int32 outBufferSize,
>   System.IO.Pipes.PipeSecurity pipeSecurity) [0x00000] in :0    at System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeServerStream..ctor
>   (System.String pipeName, PipeDirection direction, Int32
>   maxNumberOfServerInstances, PipeTransmissionMode transmissionMode,
>   PipeOptions options, Int32 inBufferSize, Int32 outBufferSize)
>   [0x00000] in :0    at
>   System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeServerStream..ctor (System.String pipeName,
>   PipeDirection direction, Int32 maxNumberOfServerInstances,
>   PipeTransmissionMode transmissionMode, PipeOptions options) [0x00000]
>   in :0    at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check)
>   System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeServerStream:.ctor
>   (string,System.IO.Pipes.PipeDirection,int,System.IO.Pipes.PipeTransmissionMode,System.IO.Pipes.PipeOptions)
>   at ConsoleTestPipeApp1.Program.ListenForPipeServer () [0x00000] in
>   /Users/Vadivelu/Project/Service_Test/ConsoleTestPipeApp1/ConsoleTestPipeApp1/Program.cs:21
>   at ConsoleTestPipeApp1.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000]
>   in
>   /Users/Vadivelu/Project/Service_Test/ConsoleTestPipeApp1/ConsoleTestPipeApp1/Program.cs:16

Answer (score 0):

The only problem is that the pipe named "testPipe" that you are using does not exist when the C# code is accessing the pipe. If you first run the command `mkfifo testPipe` (on unix) and then run the following C# code, it should work.